# Printing the result of a "find_all" (using bs4 library) returns an empty list (but the class I'm referencing exists)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to create a webscraper for https://www.cappex.com/scholarships. I am trying to find every div that contains scholarship information with the class "ais-hits--item". When using find_all (from bs4), the divs I am looking for are not being returned, and I am stumped as to why. I am fairly new to python but not HTML.
[image]
There are many divs nested within each other, so I've tried finding other divs with different classes, and they all return an empty list ([]). Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.cappex.com/scholarships'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
scholarships = soup.find_all('div', class_='ais-hits--item')

print scholarships
```

I expected to have a list of the divs but the output was [].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `<div>` tags are not loaded with the page source, and therefore not capturable by `BeautifulSoup`. In other words, there is probably an event triggered in the website once it loads, and therefore `bs4` won't help you get the data. You can verify by searching the page source for the tag `ais-hits--item`.

Having that said, you can actually directly query for the data in the specific website you posted. Just bear in mind whether the website wants you to be having that access when you choose to do so.

```py
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://www.cappex.com',
    'Referer': 'https://www.cappex.com/scholarships',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36'
}

json = {"requests":[{"indexName":"prod-scholarship","params":"query=&hitsPerPage=12&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page=0&attributesToRetrieve=%5B%22name%22%2C%22administeringAgency%22%2C%22deadline%22%2C%22deadlineFormatted%22%2C%22awardAmount%22%2C%22maxAward%22%2C%22averageAwardAmount%22%2C%22variableAwardAmount%22%2C%22renewable%22%2C%22objectID%22%5D&restrictHighlightAndSnippetArrays=true&facets=%5B%22deadline%22%2C%22awardAmount%22%2C%22renewable%22%2C%22firstGeneration%22%2C%22financialNeedRequired%22%2C%22lgbtqia%22%2C%22disability%22%2C%22nonUSCitizenEligible%22%2C%22genders%22%2C%22ethnicities%22%2C%22enrollmentLevels%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}

params = {
    'x-algolia-agent': 'Algolia for vanilla JavaScript 3.27.1;instantsearch.js 2.8.0;JS Helper 2.26.0',
    'x-algolia-application-id': 'MVAUKZTA2I',
    'x-algolia-api-key': 'd9568940e07ac01d868893e44be784e8'
}

url = 'https://mvaukzta2i-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params, json=json)
```

This will get all data for the website. For instance:

```py
results = r.json()['results']

results[0]['hits'][0]
Out[1]:
{'administeringAgency': 'My Best Mattress',
 'renewable': False,
 'name': 'MyBestMattress Scholarship',
 'deadlineFormatted': 'July 31, 2020',
 'awardAmount': 700.0,
 'averageAwardAmount': 700.0,
 'deadline': 1596153600000.0,
 'variableAwardAmount': False,
 'objectID': '52049',
 '_highlightResult': {'administeringAgency': {'value': 'My Best Mattress',
   'matchLevel': 'none',
   'matchedWords': []},
  'name': {'value': 'MyBestMattress Scholarship',
   'matchLevel': 'none',
   'matchedWords': []},
  'deadlineFormatted': {'value': 'July 31, 2020',
   'matchLevel': 'none',
   'matchedWords': []},
  'awardAmount': {'value': '700.0', 'matchLevel': 'none', 'matchedWords': []},
  'id': {'value': '52049', 'matchLevel': 'none', 'matchedWords': []},
  'averageAwardAmount': {'value': '700.0',
   'matchLevel': 'none',
   'matchedWords': []},
  'deadline': {'value': '1.5961536E+12',
   'matchLevel': 'none',
   'matchedWords': []}}}
```